# cannot access file in a tomcat webapp

Tags: java, tomcat

i have a tomcat webapp which is called "app". Inside the folder tomcat/webapps/app/ is a file named index.html (as you can see in the screenshot) 
[image]

when i start my tomcat and try to access the file with the url

```
http://localhost:8080/app/index.html
```

then i get a 404 - not found error. What am I doing propably wrong? I allready checked the rights of the tomcat directory on the filesystem and have all rights to access all files in the directory

Thank you in advance!

Comment: try this http://localhost:8080/app

Comment: i get the same error message

Comment: could it be a problem that i start the tomcat with "catalina jpda start" ?

Comment: i think that should be fine, this looks like a filesystem permission issue to me

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm try by changing permissions on the folder and make sure you apply the permission recursively (so this step "Replace all child object permissions with inheritable permissions from this object") so all the folders underneath your tomcat take the same command like here: https://serverfault.com/questions/157461/set-permissions-recursively-on-windows-7

Answer (score 0):

Use the Sysinternals Process Monitor to see where Tomcat is looking for files when you do the HTTP request. This will help you understand what's going on.